# Changing Texture on an Object under certain condition

Tags: java, opengl, textures, jogl

I have a problem with textures in Jogl. I draw a bookshelf and when the shelf is detected as marked the texture should change. Here is my code so far:

```
    Texture book;

    if (Library.touchTime != 0 && Library.marked.equals(name)){
        long actTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (actTime - Library.touchTime <= 2000){
            this.book = books_marked;
        }
        else{
            Library.touchTime = 0;
            Library.marked = "";
            this.book = books;
        }
    }
    book.enable();
    book.bind();

//---- front --------------------------------------------------
    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_QUADS);
        normVector = front.getNorm();
        gl.glNormal3f(normVector.getX(), normVector.getY(), normVector.getZ());
        drawRect(gl, 0, 1, 2, 3);
    gl.glEnd();
```

The Objects books and books_marked are parameters of the constructor and are created like this:

```
// ---- Load Book Texture -----------------------------------------------
    try {
        InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("books.jpg");
        data = TextureIO.newTextureData(stream, false, "jpg");
        books = TextureIO.newTexture(data);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }

// -------------------------------------------------------------
// ---- Load Book_marked Texture -------------------------------------
    try {
        InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("books_marked.jpg");
        data = TextureIO.newTextureData(stream, false, "jpg");
        books_marked = TextureIO.newTexture(data);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My intent was to instanciate the book Texture-Object within the if condition so that the bind() command would automatically bind the correct Picture. But the Texture doesn't change. Has anybody an idea what I got wrong here?

Comment: Did you make sure, that your `if`-condition is actually working as expected?

Comment: Yes, I did. I had output on the consol showing the time running so it works fine.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you but you're still using JOGL 1 which is no longer maintained. Rather switch to JOGL 2 even though it won't be enough to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Call Texture.bind(GL) or glBindTexture.